# Want to show name as a parameter instead of id in the URL field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I don't want to show `/route_name/{id}` in the URL field of my Laravel project. Instead of that I want to show `/route_name/{name}` and also pass the `id` in the back-end to the controller.

Suppose I have a view `department.blade.php`. Now click on `knee pain` from the menubar for seeing the details. Here is my view code

```
<a href="{{ url('/home_services_under_department/'.$data->id) }}>
   {{$data->name}}
</a>"
```

After click the `knee pain` a route called. Here is the route

```
Route::get('/home_services_under_department/{id}', 'frontendDepartmentController@home_services_under_department');
```

Here is the `home_services_under_department` method format

```
public function home_services_under_department($id){}
```

Here is my URL in browser
http://url/home_services_under_department/2

But I don't want to see the `id` after  `home_services_under_department`, I want to see the name `knee-pain` after `home_services_under_department` as a parameter like

```
http://url/home_services_under_department/knee-pain
```

and also want to pass the `id` to the controller method.

Is it possible in Laravel ?

Comment: It is! Replace `id` with `name` in your routes and controller and `find()` the correct model in your action

Comment: @ kerbholz...for that I think I need unique name for all my department name...right ? and in the `find()` function I pass the name as a parameter to find the id .. am I right ?

Comment: right... you will need unique name.. that is why $id is commonly used

Comment: You can do one thing replace all space from name with (-) add id at the end, So each name will be unique like knee-pain-1 and in your controller you can get id by just splitting  that segment .

Comment: You could use Laravel's `str_slug()` to create a slug from the name/title of your model (make sure it's unique)

Comment: @Ahsan...That's a kind of solution. But do you think it's the proper solution ? Bcz `id` is unique always. There is no risk of conflict with others `id`. But there is a risk in `name`....Do you understand what I mean to say?

Comment: in that case check Saini and kerbholz's solution. you can either append id at the end of name or use slug

Comment: @ R.K.Saini....nice thinking .. :)

Comment: @ kerbholz.... I find the idea from your comment. You can give a post and I will accept that as an answer if you want... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the **name** and can retrieve **ID** from the database.

**1. href**

```
     <a href="{{ url('/home_services_under_department/'.$data->name) }}>
         {{$data->name}}
     </a>
```

**2. route**

```
     Route::get('/home_services_under_department/{name}', 
     'frontendDepartmentController@home_services_under_department');
```

**3. function**

```
      public function home_services_under_department($name){
           $data= Model_name::select('id')->where('name', $name)->first();
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first pass name in the url then in the controller retrieve the id using the name and proccess with the id whatever you want to do then again return the url with name so that it wont be visible in the url and in the frontend
If you want to secure more , encrypt/hash the name in url with proper algorithm and retrieve it and process it

Answer (score 0):

You should update your route and view file code like:

Route

```
Route::get('/home_services_under_department/{id}', 'frontendDepartmentController@home_services_under_department')->name('homeservicedepartment');
```

**department.blade.php**

```
<a href="{{ route('homeservicedepartment', [$data->id]) }}">{{$data->name}}</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to show the `id` as a parameter in the URL. But in your solution I think it's the same

Comment: @raff: So what you want in Url Parameter?

Comment: @raff: Ok means you need to both name and id when you click on link

Comment: @ AddWeb Solution Pvt Ltd.....Yes. But I don't want to show the `id` in my URL as a parameter...just want to show the `name` as a parameter in the URL. And as well as want to pass the `id` in the controller method....

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.

If you want to "pass" the id, either you put in in the URL (that is a 'GET') or send a 'POST' and pass the id as one of the parameters. Of course, you can't send a post with a simple link , but you can fake a post to look like a link.

```html
<style>
    form.link_mimic {display:inline}
    form.link_mimic input {display:inline;padding:0;border-width:0;margin:0;background:none;color:blue}
    form.link_mimic input:hover {text-decoration:underline}
</style>

<form class="link_mimic" method="post" action="my_url">
  <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="blah">
  <input type="submit" value="this is a form">
</form>
```